# How to accept boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> as an argument of type boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, tcp

I was trying to adapt the SSL server example in the Boost docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.cpp) but I would like to make an application where you can use normal `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` or an SSL socket but I haven't found a good way to pass either to a function like `void do_something_with_socket(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock)` because the SSL socket doesn't inherit from the raw TCP socket.  The only thing I can think of is to use templates everywhere but I was wondering if there is any better way to do this?  Thanks.

Edit: I've looked through the members of `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>` and I've found `next_layer()` is a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` but I've tried it and it doesn't encrypt the data because I guess this is the raw socket the SSL stream uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [lowest_layer()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/lowest_layer.html) instead of next layer.

For example, this asio [HTTP library](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib) uses"templates everywhere" and connects an SSL socket with the following code:

```
void connect_socket(ConnectHandler connect_handler,
                    ASIO::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator host_iterator)
{ ASIO::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), host_iterator, connect_handler); }
```

Where `socket_` is a `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`.